# Can't install Webmin from sources.list getting Hash Sum mismatch in 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, updates, 16.04, webmin

**Installing Webmin**

```bsh
echo "deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webmin.list
cd /root
wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
apt-key add jcameron-key.asc
rm jcameron-key.asc
apt-get update && apt-get install webmin -y
```

```bsh
root@Ubuntu:~# apt-get install webmin -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apt-show-versions libapt-pkg-perl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-show-versions libapt-pkg-perl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
  webmin
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.2 MB/28.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 159 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge/contrib amd64 webmin all 1.791 [28.2 MB]
Err:1 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge/contrib i386 webmin all 1.791    
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:1 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge/contrib i386 webmin all 1.791 [28.2 MB]
Err:1 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge/contrib all webmin all 1.791     
  Hash Sum mismatch
Err:1 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge/contrib all webmin all 1.791     
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 49.9 MB in 21s (2,325 kB/s)                                                         
E: Failed to fetch http://download.webmin.com/download/repository/pool/contrib/w/webmin/webmin_1.791_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@Ubuntu:~#
```

Comment: it looks like you are in root already so try typing `apt-get autoclean` maybe `apt-get clean`  then  `apt-get update --fix-missing`  then try to install again

Comment: @JohnOrion Still am getting the same error :(

Comment: try going to `http://download.webmin.com/download/repository/pool/contrib/w/webmin/webmin_1.791_all.deb` manually downloading it then put it in ...  the  apt  cache directory .. `/var/cache/apt/archives/` then try the install again .. or just try to install it from the deb file

Comment: @JohnOrion That worked but I do not want to have to do that everytime I would like to update Webmin.

Comment: you probably wont .. you probably had a corrupted version in the cache and it just kept trying to install it.. if you did the first way .. it put  a  non corrupted file in the cache and  installed that instead ... if you just installed from the download then ... it probably either copied that install to the cache or the next version  will download a new one anyway

Comment: @JohnOrion I just installed a fresh version of Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS and it is doing it again so I am just going to have to add it to the cache I guess.

Comment: yeah .. its probably corrupt on the server and for some reason a direct download either doesnt corrupt it or maybe since i think you are installing it from the deb package rather than using the package manager ..  maybe its allowing it to install past the  corruption.. but again .. the next version will probably work fine... or you could try to remove it from the cache then change your source .. download server

Comment: @JohnOrion I found out that installing Webmin on ubuntu 14.04LTS works perfictly fine unlike Ubuntu 16.04LTS Which gives you `Hash Sum mismatch`

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the withdrawal of SHA1 checksums in 16.04

> Tomorrow ... APT will see a new release, turning of[f] support for
>   SHA-1 checksums in Debian unstable and in Ubuntu Xenial, the upcoming
>   LTS release.  While I have no knowledge of an imminent attack on our
>   use of SHA1, Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) will be supported for 5 years,
>   and the landscape may change a lot in the next 5 years. As disabling
>   the SHA1 support requires a bit of patching in our test suite, it’s
>   best to do that now rather than later when we’re forced to do it.

https://juliank.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/dropping-sha-1-support-in-apt/